Adjusting stem angle
I know this question was asked few times but I can't find one that would help me.
I can't adjust angle of the stem. According to bike instruction I should only need to loosen screw on the right but I feel like that's not true. I tried that but stem still won't budge. I took it apart, still nothing. There is small hole from the bottom but it's not a screw. I also tried to loosen top screw.
The bike is KALKHOFF Endeavour 22





Not relevant to you, but perhaps to others that stumble on this question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/50557/6852

The second photo suggests that when loosening the lock bolt to change the stem angle, it should allow the inner toothed flange (to call it something) to shrink and give enough clearance for the teeth to disengaged from the outer teeth flunge. Try spraying some WD40 between the teeth and try loosening it carefully with a hammer using a piece of wood between your stem and the hammer to avoid scratching the paint.

Thank you, that helped!
